# Regex: Capturing Numbers at Beginning and Negating Numbers After Characters

Tags: r, regex

I need to capture the 3.93, 4.63999..., and -5.35. I've tried all kinds of variations, but have been unable to grab the correct set of numbers.

Copay: 20.30

3.93

TAB 8.6MG Qty:60

4.6399999999999997

-5.35

2,000UNIT TAB Qty:30

AMOUNT

Qty:180

CAP 4MG

Comment: So you need to capture lines that only have numbers, decimals, and negative signs? What exactly did you try that didn't work?

Comment: if you have multiple rows or lines, why not doing something like `as.numeric(line)` and then removing NAs. I don't see the need for regex here.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what exactly qualifies these numbers for your match (and what disqualifies the others)? The way your question is worded, you could simply use the pattern `3\.93|4\.63999\d*|-5\.35`.

Comment: Showing a complete desired output is a very easy way to convey what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = c("Copay: 20.30", "3.93", "TAB 8.6MG Qty:60", "4.6399999999999997", "-5.35", "2,000UNIT TAB Qty:30", "AMOUNT", "Qty:180", "CAP 4MG");
grep("^[\\-]?\\d+[\\.]?\\d+$", x);
```

Output (see [`?grep`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/grep)):

```
[1] 2 4 5
```

If leading/trailing spaces are allowed change the `regex` with

```
"^\\s*[\\-]?\\d+[\\.]?\\d+\\s*$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
S <- c("Copay: 20.30", "3.93", "TAB 8.6MG Qty:60", "4.6399999999999997", "-5.35", "2,000UNIT TAB Qty:30", "AMOUNT", "Qty:180", "CAP 4MG")

library(stringr)
ans <- str_extract_all(S, "-?[[:digit:]]*(\\.|,)?[[:digit:]]+", simplify=TRUE)
clean <- ans[ans!=""]
```

Output

```
 [1] "20.30"              "3.93"               "8.6"               
 [4] "4.6399999999999997" "-5.35"              "2,000"             
 [7] "180"                "4"                  "60"                
[10] "30"
```